# How to get property level serialization error while using JsonPatchDocument<T> in .NET Core WebApi during PATCH calls

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, json-patch

I am implementing HTTP Patch using JsonPatch library from .NET Core.(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson).
MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Am able to do partial updates using JsonPatch with the below code.

DTO:

```
public class Customer{
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
   public string ZipCode;
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPatch]
public IActionResult JsonPatchWithModelState([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Customer> patchDoc)
{
   var customer = GetExistingCustomerFromDatabase();
   patchDoc.ApplyTo(customer, ModelState);

   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }

    return new ObjectResult(customer);
}
```

Sample Postman: (Valid data scenario) [Name property updated as expected]

```
Request:
{
  "op":"replace",
  "path": "/name",
  "value": "updated-name-XYZ"
}

Response: 200(OK)
```

When the value of "Name" property is an invalid data type; below response is returned.

Sample Postman: (Invalid data Scenario) [For example: Trying to pass a dictionary object]

```
Request:
{
  "op":"replace",
  "path": "/name",
  "value": {"key123": "value123"}
}

Response: 400(Bad Request)
Response Body:
{
    "Customer": [
        "The value '{\r\n  \"key123\": \"value123\"\r\n}' is invalid for target location."
    ]
}
```

When the above request is sent to the HTTP action method, the breakpoint hits.
At that instant ModelState.IsValid = true, after patch is applied:

```
 patchDoc.ApplyTo(customer, ModelState);
```

ModelState.IsValid becomes false. And BadRequest(400) is returned.

Is there a way to catch this invalid data type even before patch is applied to get a detailed error message. Or does JsonPatch support throwing specific error message at property level(here: "Name"), instead of entity level(here: "Customer")?

Required response body:

```
Response: 400(Bad Request)
Response Body:
{
    "Name": [
        "The input was not valid."
    ]
}
```

This is the error message for POST or PUT during invalid data scenario.

And Breakpoint will not be hit at action method, due to the serializable error:

```
"Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type '\"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError\"'.", "Type":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.SerializableError"
```

Can similar behavior be achieved with JsonPatch also? Is there way to catch serializable errors with DTO classes while using JsonPatchDocument?

Or any custom validator approaches will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name":{
           "key123": "value123"
         }
}
```

Try to [replace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.3) the value at key not name with a new value.

```
{
  "op":"replace",
  "path": "/name/key123",
  "value": "value1234"
}
```

Comment: But in my case, the value is not controlled.The user can enter any input. Since "value" property accepts an object, wanted to restrict the value to only strings.  I do not want to change the request format.

Comment: Hi, @randy107, sorry for my poor understanding of this question. But I think [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help u to get more assistant.